# How to center vertically and horizontally a heading text using dash-bootstrap

Tags: css, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I'm using [Bootstrap dash layout](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/l/components/layout) for my web application layout. But instead of having the text at the top of the page, I wish the text will be in the red area. How can I achieve it?

[image: Text in the red area]

I've tried using `"align":"center" and "justify":"center"` but nothing helps

```
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc 
import dash_html_components as html 
import dash

body = dbc.Container([ 
dbc.Row(
            [
            html.H1("test")
            ], justify="center", align="center"
            )
]

)

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SUPERHERO])

app.layout = html.Div([body])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Understand there is some workaround using [flask-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38555814/how-to-center-vertically-and-horizontally-a-heading-text-using-flask-bootstrap) but how do I do the same using dash-plotly-booststrap?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After searching through the developers' github I found this [Closed issue](https://github.com/facultyai/dash-bootstrap-components/issues/286), It turns out you can set the height of the dash's Row using the Container's `style`parameter and setting up the height using the `className="h-50"` . So the solution looks something like this:

```
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc 
import dash_html_components as html 
import dash

body = dbc.Container([ 
dbc.Row(
            [
            html.H1("test")
            ], justify="center", align="center", className="h-50"
            )
],style={"height": "100vh"}

)

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SUPERHERO])

app.layout = html.Div([body])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```