# how to center a image in python dash?

Tags: python, css, bootstrap-4, plotly-dash

I am trying to center a image when doing the flask dash app, here is my code:

```
import dash
from dash import html, dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.CardImg(src=r'assets/welcome.png', className = 'align-self-center')
    ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

but this is not work for me, the image is still on the left not centered.

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59499025/how-to-center-vertically-and-horizontally-a-heading-text-using-dash-bootstrap)

Comment: no, this is used for center a text, I can do that for sure but image still has the issue

Comment: You've used a flexbox centering mechanism. Please provide more layout context so good answers can be given.

Answer (score 0):

I figure myself, just add an assets folder under the path and add a .css file input:

```
.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

and then call this class in the dash layout:

```
html.Img(src=r'assets/welcome.png',style={'height': '20%','width': '20%'} ,className = 'center')
```

Comment: Bootstrap provides everything you need to center things. You shouldn't be writing custom styles for this.